# Dynamically created ImageView is not rotated

Tags: android, matrix, imageview, android-imageview

When I load `ImageView` from xml and rotate it works as expected, however
while creating `ImageView` in class it is not worked as expected.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_main);
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    //iv = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image));

    iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    layout.addView(iv);
    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    iv.setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
    iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    rotateXform();
}

private void rotateXform() {
    if (isRotationOriginalValue) {
        mMatrix.postRotate((float) 180, centerX, centerY);
    } else {
        mMatrix.postRotate((float) -180, centerX, centerY);
    }
    isRotationOriginalValue = !isRotationOriginalValue;
    iv.setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
    iv.invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the Image but its background.

An `ImageView`, like any other view, can have a Background, which is independent of the image itself. Normally the background is hidden behind the image, but if you set padding, or use a semi-transparent image, you will see both things.

So just replace

```
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

with

```
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

and you'll see it rotated.

Comment: I have already edited my code , it was partly copied the code,and it was missed,even using setImageResource() it shows as not rotated ImageView

Comment: assuming you initialize `mMatrix = new Matrix()` elsewhere, I see nothing wrong with your code. It should rotate!